# i am trying to understand what does this query means?

Tags: mysql, join

```
select user.*,
store.storeId,store.storeName from 
user JOIN store ON user.storeId=store.storeId 
where email=? and password=?
```

This is my mysql query thought of when joining the table but i am not able to get what my query is doing i am unable to get that.

Comment: Without data this isn't really a complete question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select everything from the user table.

```
select user.*,
```

Select storeId and storeName from the store table.

```
store.storeId,store.storeName
```

join the 2 tables together where the storeId from user table is = to storeId in the store table where the email and pass = what they typed in the input

```
from 
user JOIN store ON user.storeId=store.storeId 
where email=? and password=?
```

Comment: let me know if you have any questions. Glad to Help

Comment: No problem glad to help